# if two or more entry in last column, make independent row for each entry

Tags: awk

I have a file in following format

```
a 2 10 a,c
b 5 8 c
b 7 2 a
c 9 0 c,d,a
```

Now for those who have multiple entries in the last column, I want a new line (column 1-3 remaining same) for each of the entry in the last column in the following format

```
a 2 10 a
a 2 10 c
b 5 8 c
b 7 2 a
c 9 0 d
c 9 0 c
c 9 0 a
```

Some suggestion please.

Comment: Does the solution have to be for `awk`?

Comment: Not necessarily. I was going through different post here and feels awk can solve it.

Comment: Are the order of the last three lines correct? should it not be  `c` `d` and `a`?  You have `d` `c` `a`

Comment: I apologize Jotne. You are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use spaces and commas as the field separator, then print the 1st,2nd,3rd and `i`th field from the 4th field onward:

```
awk -F'[[:space:],]+' '{for(i=4;i<=NF;++i)print $1,$2,$3,$i}' file
```

Output:

```
a 2 10 a
a 2 10 c
b 5 8 c
b 7 2 a
c 9 0 c
c 9 0 d
c 9 0 a
```

If you're not adverse to a bit of Perl:

```
perl -F'[,\s]+' -lane 'print "@F[0..2,$_]" for 3..$#F' file
```

Again, split the line on commas and spaces. More or less the same logic as the awk one but a couple of characters shorter :)

Comment: You can quote the array instead of setting the list separator variable. This will output exactly the same way `perl -F'[,\s]+' -lane 'print "@F[0..2,$_]" for 3..$#F' file`

Comment: I was sure it wasn't required but I couldn't remember why! Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. I typically use the list separator variable when I want to join the array elements with something other than a single space (like `,` or `:` etc) which could easily be achieved using `join` as well, but `TIMTOWDI` I suppose. `:)`. All these special variables will be removed from `perl 6` to make it a little more saner for the faint hearted.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
$ awk '{n=split($NF,ary,/,/); NF--; for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print $0, ary[i]}' file
a 2 10 a
a 2 10 c
b 5 8 c
b 7 2 a
c 9 0 c
c 9 0 d
c 9 0 a
```

We split the last field on `,` and store the fields in an array called `ary`. The `split` returns the number of fields splitted which we store in a variable `n`. We remove the last field from the line using `NF--` and iterate through the number of elements (from the last field) and print the line along with the element from our `ary`.